# HowTo detect tap on map annotaition Pin?

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios4, mapkit

I want to detect tap on annotation pin(of `mapkit`) so that I can perform action on that event.

Now the default annotation flag pops up in case I touch the annotation pin. I want to customise that to call my method when pin is touched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement the following delegate method

```
 (MKAnnotationView) mapView viewForAnnotation:(id) annotation
```

Then just declare following in this method

```
MKPinAnnotationView *view=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation  reuseIdentifier:@"abc"];
view.canShowCallout=YES;
view.calloutOffset=CGPointMake(-20,10); //As per your choice
```

Then you can add UI to your callout eg UIButton or UIImage as
   view.rightCalloutAccesoryView
   View.leftCalloutAccesoryView

Comment: ...and when the callout is tapped, it will call the `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` delegate method (no addTarget or gesture recognizer needed).

Comment: If you don't want the standard callout, you can also detect tap using `mapView:didSelectAnnotationView:`.

Comment: Hi, @AnnaKarenina, mapView:didSelectAnnotationView doesn't work well. Cause if you tap the same annotation twice, the second tap will be ignored.

Answer (score -1):

As pin on map is `MKAnnotationView` you can add `UITapGestureRecognizer` on it(of yours), but if it already has some `GestureRecognizer` than you will need to remove it first.

Thanks